# Prevent capacitor discharge after it was charged using a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, adc, dac, discharge

I want to use a micro-controller (like an Arduino) to:

- Charge an external capacitor
- Measure voltage across the capacitor
- Capacitor discharge rate as low as possible.
- Capacitor discharge rate while using ADC to measure voltage as low as possible.

The microcontroller has

- DAC (to charge capacitor)
- ADC (to measure capacitance)
- Multiplexer to attach DAC/ADC to whatever pin you want
- I use a multimeter to measure resitance between pin 0 and pin 1 = 1Mohm (Q1 is pin0-1 resistance called chip resitance? What is the name?)

I can attach a capacitor between pins 0 and 1 however it will discharge as 1Mohm resitance isn't very high.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhR0Hu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Question**:

1. Is the pin 0 to 1 resistance called chip resistance? What is the name?
2. How can I reduce the capacitor discharge after I charge it with the DAC?
3. How can I reduce the discharge while measuring voltage with ADC?

My actual chip is the [NHS3152](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/NHS3152-1152134.pdf). I am looking for any solution, even one with other components to be added.

**EDIT EXTRA CONTEXT INFORMATION**

I was thinking of using the capacitor as an X-ray detector:

1. X-rays would interact with the dielectric to create e-h pairs
2. The electric field present on the charged capacitor would separate the charges
3. This would affect voltage across capacitance.
4. Measure the voltage with NHS3152 and have a working device.

If the capacitor discharges over time, then the field within the dielectric would change, separating the e-h pairs less, so low-discharge is important.

Comment: what's the purpose?

Comment: *I use a multimeter to measure Resitance between Pin0 & Pin1 = 1Mohm ( Q1 is Pin0-1 resistance caleld chip resitance? what is the name?* That is a **meaningless** measurement. Depending on **how** you measure and/or configure the chip, you will get completely different values. Why? Because those pins are IO pins and that means they can be configured as input/output/ with or without pullup (and/or down) resistor or they can be tri-state and have a high impedance. This all when the chip is in operation (powered on).

Comment: All-in-all: there's a complex circuit connected to those pins, measuring the resistance with a multimeter is **pointless**. You are just fooling yourself if you think that that gives you reliable information. I also agree with @user253751: explain **WHY** you do this, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "as 1Mohm resitance isn't very high" Eh? 1 Megaohm _is_ very high, especially for the purpose of charging/discharging caps. Are you sure you don't mean _milliohm_, `m` prefix, like they taught us back in school _way_ before enrolling in actual engineering studies?

Comment: Buy a sample and hold.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie thanks, so the resitance between the pins can depend on the configuration of the pins, even while it is powered off? I measure the 1Mohm resitance even when powered off. But i can look into tri-state thanks for the tip

Comment: @user253751, we are thinking of using the capacitor to measure radiation. So Ionizing radiation would cause e-h pairs in the capacitors dielectric, this would create an electric field, and we can measure it with the chip. 
Usually we do a similar detection with transistors we fabricate ourselves (the dielectric of the transistor accumulates charge, changing VGS, changing IDS). I was curious whether an off-the-shelf capacitor could work in a similar way: Accumulate charge in the dielectric --> measure Voltage across the capacitor --> find out radiation exposure.

Comment: @Lundin, 1Mohm, I did the calculations for: C=2200uF, V0=1.5, R=1Mohm, after 1hr i got a Voltage of 0.29V - perhpas i misscalulated? For my application I am hoping to have negligible discharge in 1 day

Comment: @Leo Use magnetic relay (ILS) to charge then disconnect ... and opamp with femtoamp current capabilities for measuring ... Be carefull for leakage currents ! All in "flying" wires ... "Spider web" ? :-)    https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmp7721.pdf this is a good choice ... Keep it "cool" !

Comment: Or perhaps this https://www.st.com/en/amplifiers-and-comparators/tsv611.html

Comment: Consider using a MOSFET-based amplifier circuit to detect the voltage without affecting it, since MOSFETs have insulated gates. You can design one with theoretically no leakage current. You can have the capacitor voltage control a separate current which your microcontroller can measure. Actually my first thought was a gold-leaf electroscope :)

Comment: @Leo Discharge of 1000 uF from 1 V to 0.5 V in 700,000 seconds (8 days) on R=1000 Meg. Good luck :-) .  I hope a 1000uF has no leakage. A 1 nF discharge in ... 1 second. You need material such teflon to make your circuitry ... or really "spider web" in dry air.

Comment: "Discharge of 1000 uF" I dare to say that **ANY** capacitor above ~ 10 uF and **ANY** electrolytic capacitor will have so much leakage **by itself** that your experiment will fail if you use such type of capacitors. Also: **ALL** ICs have ESD protections at their inputs and these also leak current, make sure that that leakage doesn't affect your experiment. My guess is that that will be a challenge.

Comment: *we are thinking of using the capacitor to measure radiation.* And that text should have been included in the question! Not in a comment.

Comment: To measure "radiation", it would be interesting to use "spikes" correlated in some direction, with  "spherical detectors" on "short times" ...

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie "that text should have been included in the question!" I'm getting comments like these a lot in Electrical engineering, I try and remove all unnecessary information so that the question can be easy to read and useful for future viewers, however obviously i need to add more context. It's probably because i'm used to stack overflow where you just give a core reproducible problem. thanks.

Comment: @user253751 "Consider using a MOSFET-based amplifier circuit to detect the voltage" thanks. We have thought of this design. Since we detect charge accumulated in the dielectric (from X-ray interaction), we have thought of 3 designs: 1) Current design = just Transistor: charge from X-ray accumulated in gate dielectric --> measure IDS so no interaction with gate. 2) just capacitor as in question above measure voltage drop over capacitor 3) capacitor attached to transistor as you mentioned. this is probably the best option.

Comment: Cap attached to the transistor's gate  has the advantage that i can use a stable commercial transistor for readout, and just optimize the capacitor materials/size for X-ray detection. Still would need to charge up the capacitor so that it is applying an electric field to the dielectric (helps separate the e-h pairs created from the x-ray).

Comment: Instead of a transistor (discrete MOSFET) I would recommend an **opamp** with MOSFET inputs, for example: TLC271, it has input currents of a few pA at 25 C. Why not a discrete transistor: because discrete MOSFETs are often large devices for switching possibly resulting in more leakage current and also there will be a voltage drop due to the \$V_{th}\$ of the MOSFET. An opamp can be used as a buffer which will allow you to measure the actual capacitor voltage.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, "all ICs have ESD protection ... also leak current" had no idea, thanks! 
Ok so  if i've understood: 10uF is the upper limit - smaller the better.

Comment: You will need to study datasheets and look at if any leakage is specified. If it is not you might want to make a test setup and just measure it. You will need to do something like that anyway, see what happens with/without the X-ray to prove that your scheme actually works (or not).

Comment: @Leo also don't discount the possibility of using some special or weird device, especially as this is an experimental project. Don't feel like you have to just build a regular circuit out of regular components. For example, maybe coating the circuit in some particular chemical helps reduce leakage. Maybe you build your own capacitor. This is not uncommon in scientific research. I suppose if your goal is to make a cheap device then you do have to just use off-the-shelf parts.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, i might just buy a few cap and test it as you suggest. Ok so just to be clear (never used Opamp before) - I would use the opamp as a "voltage follower circuit" this would allow me to read the voltage without drawing current as it has high impedance? So I would read the Opamp output voltage with my microcontroller?

Comment: @user253751, right now we are make our own Thin film transistors (X-ray for e-h pairs in dielectric -- h accumulate at dielectric semiconductor interface -- change Vth -- we measure IDS). But currently am wondering what performances you can get with commercial components. The commercial component aren't so much for price, more for stability: R&D transistors have Vth drift, sometimes higher leakage etc. So trying to use stable commercial devices would show me what can be obtained with off-the-shelf, to put real numbers to other options.

Comment: *I would use the opamp as a "voltage follower circuit" this would allow me to read the voltage without drawing current as it has high impedance? So I would read the Opamp output voltage with my microcontroller?* Yes, that is exactly the idea.  *R&D transistors have Vth drift* Don't think commercially available MOSFETs are any better, their Vth is also depedent on temperature and varies between devices. That's why opamps are "better", then feedback eliminates all non-idealities and variations.